# Does pdksh (public domain kornShell) support associative arrays?

Tags: arrays, shell, cygwin, ksh, pdksh

I recently ran up against a wall doing some bash shell programming where an associative array would have solved my problems.  I googled about features of the KornShell (ksh) and learned that it supports associative arrays, so I installed Cygwin's pdksh (Public Domain KornShell).

However, when trying to create an associative array in the prescribed manner (typeset -A varName), I received the following errors, so I'm beginning to suspect pdksh does not support associative arrays.

```
./find_actions.ksh: line 2: typeset: -A: invalid option
typeset: usage: typeset [-afFirtx] [-p] name[=value] ...
```

Guess I will be considering Perl instead, but I really wanted a good excuse to learn a dialect/language new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at ksh93, it supports associative arrays and is a much more complete/correct implementation of ksh.

See: [kornshell.com](http://kornshell.com/)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be available in cygwin; pdksh is the only ksh-like shell.

Answer (score 1):

pdksh doesn't have any support for associative arrays; it’s a planned and definite feature of its successor, mksh (as soon as I get around to actually implementing it, that is… sorry for being slow with that).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use bash? It might not have explicit associative arrays, but you can [fake them](http://linuxshellaccount.blogspot.com/2008/05/how-to-fake-associative-arrays-in-bash.html).

Alternatively, zsh has [excellent associative array support](http://zsh.dotsrc.org/Doc/Release/zsh_14.html#SEC72).

Comment: bash version 4 [has associative arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays).